# In BASH, find folders that match different names

Tags: bash, find

I would like to find all my sub-folders that match with different names and that are older than X days

I tried with just one name:

```
find my_folder -maxdepth 3 -type d -name "*mine*" -mtime +30
```

This works ok. I don't know how to extend this in order to match also folders with "test" and "older" names

Comment: This isn't really a bash question, is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `-o` to OR the conditions and make sure to use parentheses around ORed directives:

```
find my_folder -maxdepth 3 -type d \( -name "*mine*" -o -name "*test*" -o -name "*older*" \) -mtime +30
```

Another alternative is using `-regex` option:

```
find my_folder -regextype posix-extended -maxdepth 3 -type d -regex '.*(minetest|older).*" -mtime +30
```